# UIModalPresentationFullScreen on iPad (iOS 5.0/5.1) sucks, Why?

Tags: ios

//on a button click inside current VC this code supposed to execute

```
 AViewController *Controller = [[AViewController alloc] initWithWithString:@"Hello"];  
    Controller.delegate = self;

  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController:Controller];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

//On iPAD everything is ok with iOS 6.0 or above BUT on iOS 5.0/5.1 blank white screen
is presented having nothing on it. If I use UIModalPresentationCurrentContext instead everything goes fine BUT gesture event on AViewController are passed to parent controller which I dont want.

```
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;//why this is not working

    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [Controller release];
    [navController release];
```

// AViewController custom init

```
- (id) initWithString:(NSString*) string
{
  self = [self initWithNibName:@"AViewController" bundle:nil];
  if(self)
  {
    self.text = string;
  }
  return self;
}

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
      // Custom initialization

   }
   return self;
 }
```

Comment: All other presentation styles are working besides "UIModalPresentationFullScreen".